# converting unicode to json data in python

Tags: python, json, unicode

I am getting data = `"{\"share_content\":\"dfbgfbfb\",\"campaign_media_url\":\"\",\"shorten_url\":null,\"media_shorten_url\":null,\"og_meta_data\":{\"site_name\":\"Inquirly\",\"description\":null,\"title\":null,\"url\":\"https://s3.amazonaws.com/campaign.ezeees.com/Ukb/a15Hh/index.html\",\"image\":null,\"site\":\"beta.inquirly.com\",\"type\":\"article\"},\"tw_meta_data\":{\"description\":null,\"title\":null,\"url\":\"https://s3.amazonaws.com/campaign.ezeees.com/Ukb/a15Hh/index.html\",\"image\":null,\"site\":\"@markethubs\",\"card\":\"summary_large_image\"},\"sms_content\":\"dfbgfbfb\",\"email_subject\":\"dfbgfbfb\",\"footer\":{\"fb_feed_name\":\"smartmbbs\",\"fb_feed_caption\":\"smartmbbs | VIA INQUIR.LY\",\"fb_description\":\"\",\"ln_title\":null}}"`

When I try to find type of the data variable I am getting `<type 'unicode'>`.
I have tried different ways using `json.loads` and `json.dumps` but failed to get `share_content` value from the data. I am getting different issues like string indices must be integers, etc.

My code :

```
 campaign_data = dbsession.execute("SELECT campaign_data FROM campaign_details 
                 WHERE campaign_id = '%d'"%(218)).first()
 for  row in campaign_data:
   sms_content = row
   try:
     print sms_content
     print type(sms_content)
     gst = json.loads(sms_content)
     print type(gst)
     #print json_stng['share_content']
   except (ValueError, KeyError, TypeError): 
     print "JSON format error"
     print "smssss"
```

I am getting above data variable from query as sms_content[0]

Comment: Show us the code you've tried and its result. Looks like you either have a normal JSON string, or a double-encoded JSON string. It's hard to say since it's hard to say whether you're showing us a Python literal or the raw value.

Comment: What does Unicode have to do with the question? In any case REST APIs are almost *always* Unicode, specifically UTF8. By now, almost all web sites are Unicode, eg this very site returns UTF8 pages.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's python 2 's inbuilt `unicode` type which became `str` in python 3.

Comment: @FHTMitchell and there's no Python code in this question.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `<type 'unicode'>` is the python repr for `unicode`. I'm not saying anything else except that's what OP means by "unicode".

Comment: Totaly unrelated but `for  row in campaign_data:                       sms_content = campaign_data` then working on `sms_content` is a complete WTF.

Comment: sorry bruno...i have changed the code with row...

Answer (score 1):

Use the `JSON module`

**Ex:**

```
import json
data = "{\"share_content\":\"dfbgfbfb\",\"campaign_media_url\":\"\",\"shorten_url\":null,\"media_shorten_url\":null,\"og_meta_data\":{\"site_name\":\"Inquirly\",\"description\":null,\"title\":null,\"url\":\"https://s3.amazonaws.com/campaign.ezeees.com/Ukb/a15Hh/index.html\",\"image\":null,\"site\":\"beta.inquirly.com\",\"type\":\"article\"},\"tw_meta_data\":{\"description\":null,\"title\":null,\"url\":\"https://s3.amazonaws.com/campaign.ezeees.com/Ukb/a15Hh/index.html\",\"image\":null,\"site\":\"@markethubs\",\"card\":\"summary_large_image\"},\"sms_content\":\"dfbgfbfb\",\"email_subject\":\"dfbgfbfb\",\"footer\":{\"fb_feed_name\":\"smartmbbs\",\"fb_feed_caption\":\"smartmbbs | VIA INQUIR.LY\",\"fb_description\":\"\",\"ln_title\":null}}"
print(json.loads(data))
```

**Output:**

```
{u'footer': {u'ln_title': None, u'fb_feed_name': u'smartmbbs', u'fb_description': u'', u'fb_feed_caption': u'smartmbbs | VIA INQUIR.LY'}, u'tw_meta_data': {u'description': None, u'title': None, u'url': u'https://s3.amazonaws.com/campaign.ezeees.com/Ukb/a15Hh/index.html', u'image': None, u'site': u'@markethubs', u'card': u'summary_large_image'}, u'media_shorten_url': None, u'campaign_media_url': u'', u'og_meta_data': {u'site_name': u'Inquirly', u'description': None, u'title': None, u'url': u'https://s3.amazonaws.com/campaign.ezeees.com/Ukb/a15Hh/index.html', u'image': None, u'site': u'beta.inquirly.com', u'type': u'article'}, u'sms_content': u'dfbgfbfb', u'email_subject': u'dfbgfbfb', u'shorten_url': None, u'share_content': u'dfbgfbfb'}
```

Comment: Thanks rakesh...but i tried above code...but iam getting string indices must be integers error...when i tried to print share_content as data = json.loads(data) ,print data['share_content']

Comment: Are you trying with the date mentioned above? What does `type(data)` print after  `json.loads(data)`?

Comment: What does type(data) print after json.loads(data)?

Comment: still iam getting unicode  and data as   {"share_content":"dfbgfbfb","campaign_media_url":"","shorten_url":null,"media_shorten_url":null,"og_meta_data":{"site_name":"Inquirly","description":null,"title":null,"url":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/campaign.ezeees.com/Ukb/a15Hh/index.html","image":null,"site":"beta.inquirly.com","type":"article"},"tw_meta_data":{"description":null,"title":null,"url":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/campaign.ezeees.com/Ukb/a15Hh/index.html","image":null,"site":"@markethubs","card":"summary_large_image"}"

Comment: Obviously your data has been json-encoded twice. The Q&D workaround is to json-decode them twice too, but 1/ that is brittle at best and 2/ it won't solve the root problem which is "why have those data been json-encoded twice".

Comment: @sowmya. Remove `jst =  json.dumps(sms_content[0])` directly use `gst = json.loads(sms_content[0])`

Comment: i have changed my code by removing json.dumps still iam facing the same issue @Rakesh

Answer (score -1):

Convert Unicode into utf-8 format then you can do json dumps

```
        data = "{\"share_content\":\"dfbgfbfb\",\"campaign_media_url\":\"\",\"shorten_url\":null,\"media_shorten_url\":null,\"og_meta_data\":{\"site_name\":\"Inquirly\",\"description\":null,\"title\":null,\"url\":\"https://s3.amazonaws.com/campaign.ezeees.com/Ukb/a15Hh/index.html\",\"image\":null,\"site\":\"beta.inquirly.com\",\"type\":\"article\"},\"tw_meta_data\":{\"description\":null,\"title\":null,\"url\":\"https://s3.amazonaws.com/campaign.ezeees.com/Ukb/a15Hh/index.html\",\"image\":null,\"site\":\"@markethubs\",\"card\":\"summary_large_image\"},\"sms_content\":\"dfbgfbfb\",\"email_subject\":\"dfbgfbfb\",\"footer\":{\"fb_feed_name\":\"smartmbbs\",\"fb_feed_caption\":\"smartmbbs | VIA INQUIR.LY\",\"fb_description\":\"\",\"ln_title\":null}}"
        print data.decode('utf-8')
```

Output:

```
    {"share_content":"dfbgfbfb","campaign_media_url":"","shorten_url":null,"media_shorten_url":null,"og_meta_data":{"site_name":"Inquirly","description":null,"title":null,"url":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/campaign.ezeees.com/Ukb/a15Hh/index.html","image":null,"site":"beta.inquirly.com","type":"article"},"tw_meta_data":{"description":null,"title":null,"url":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/campaign.ezeees.com/Ukb/a15Hh/index.html","image":null,"site":"@markethubs","card":"summary_large_image"},"sms_content":"dfbgfbfb","email_subject":"dfbgfbfb","footer":{"fb_feed_name":"smartmbbs","fb_feed_caption":"smartmbbs | VIA INQUIR.LY","fb_description":"","ln_title":null}}
```